# Does VSCode support to edit my code on Onedrive?

Tags: visual-studio-code, onedrive

I want to get access to Onedrive files on VSCode so that I can edit and sync **my code** on Onedrive at the same time easily, just as sync files via SSH. But it seems that there isn't an extension being able to connect to an Onedrive account (I searched the keyword "onedrive" on VSCode Marketplace). Is there another approach?

PS: The question is modified a little because of potential obfuscation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no extension to do that with OneDrive at the moment, but I plan to implement this feature on [Google Drive™ for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GustavoASC.google-drive-vscode#:%7E:text=%E2%84%A2%20for%20VSCode-,Manage%20Google%20Drive%E2%84%A2%20files%20and%20folders%20directly%20from%20VSCode,Drive%E2%84%A2%20through%20this%20extension.) extension which I published last month. It does not support editing on remote drive yet but you already can download/upload files from within VSCode.

If you have any trouble/suggestion/idea related to this extension feel free to open issues on GitHub so I can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just found that the question could be solved by `rclone sync` and it is a pity that I have't got a Google Drive ... TAT

Comment: microsoft is pretty backward in making things work. Only thing they made that works is the VSCODE, all others are total crappp. They bought the visual basic, so technically they didn't made anything which works on their own.